# Best normalization practice: Scoping all models to an organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-design

I have a ROR app that manages data like tasks and notes. It has a user model that can edit those items.

Now I want a user and all other items to belong to an organization.

My question is: What's the best practice to achieve that?

Usually I'd say: Let's just all items belong_to :organization and scope and validate it. But I can't imagine how to simplify the validations and permission checks here. Plus I don't know if it's such a good practice to just have this organization_id field in each of my database tables.

How would you solve this? How can I make sure, each item belongs to the organization and a user gets only his organization's items?

Thanks for your help and your brainstorming :)

Comment: Are you interested in a generic data model or ruby specific solution?

Comment: Well, I think the main problem is the generic data model. But for scoping and validating there's a Ruby part, of course. Either one would help. A data model would make a good common ground here for example :-)

Comment: Do the Tasks and Notes belong to an Organization, or does a User belong to an Organization, and the Tasks and Notes belong to a User? Or is there an intervening model for User-Organization to which Tasks and Notes would belong?